# Azure AD callback is not going to AuthenticateExternalAsync method

Tags: c#, google-signin, identityserver3, openid-connect, azure-active-directory

I am using `OpenID Connect` to connect to Azure ID, I can successfully authenticate in Azure and get the request coming back to the redirect uri specified in OpenID Azure AD Configuration.

`app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        AuthenticationType = " TEST",
                        Caption = "Test Azure AD",
                        SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                        ClientId = "<client ID>",
                        Authority = "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantId>",
                        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.CodeIdToken,
                        RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44392/External/Login", This is another webapi project, not identityserver host. 
                        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                    });`

After succesful authentication it is redirecting back to  `https://localhost:44392/External/Login` with Code, IdToken.

Questions :

1. Does it not stop at `AuthenticateExternalAsync` method  on redirection unlike `google-signin` ?
2. Do i have to decode `IdToken` JWT to get user claims?
3. In the redirection method, how do i generate `Access Token` from IdSrv3 to authorize other webapis ?
4. Can a user have both Local Login and Multiple External logins ( Azure AD, Google etc ). In this case how does SSO works with `IDsrv3` ?
5. Is there any `IdSrv3` sample with External logins implemented ?  Preferably Azure AD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just struggled through this process, so I'll attempt to answer as best I can to help you/others. Forgive me if I misunderstand your question.

1. `AuthenticateExternalAsync` should be called, but you need to have AzureAd return to the IDS (Identity Server) rather than to your App. Your flow should look something like: app -> IDS -> AzureAd -> IDS (AuthenticateExternalAsync) -> App.
2. In `AuthenticateExternalAsync` you get the `ExternalAuthenticationContext.ExternalIdentity`, which contains the claims - no need to decode the JWT token.
3. IDS handles this once you return a successful `AuthenticatedResult` in `AuthenticateExternalAsync`, something like `context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("UserId", name, claims);`
4. Yes. You can force the method of logging in as [described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943977/skip-identityserver3-login-screen?rq=1) for SSO purposes, otherwise I imagine IDS would handle it post first-login.
5. I found [this](http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/category/identityserver3/) helpful (runs through setup of IDS and AzureAd), but it does use the old Azure Portal rather than the new one. They don't seem to have any samples in their [gallery](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples).

Hope that helps a bit :)